# What did it mean in the actual battle when Ender froze his own legs to make shields?

Tags: enders-game

So in [Ender's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game), at a certain point, Ender figures out he can shoot his own legs to turn them into shields using this strategy to win the “war games” he was participating in.

> Later on Ender finds out he was actually directing human armies.

When Ender employed the leg freezing strategy,

> did that translate to earth forces shooting their own ships (and or soldiers) and using them as shields (and or meat shields)?

Comment: He does use the tactic of using his fighters as cannon fodder to confuse the enemy. Compare: "*Now the boys understood. Tom was a shield, an armored spacecraft, and Bean was hiding inside. He was certainly not invulnerable, but he would have time.*" to "*His commanders took their parts of the fleet and grouped themselves into a thick projectile, a cylinder aimed at the nearest of the enemy formations.*"

Comment: Those were actual games. Not the same part of the story. How did you manage to get these details without getting their context?

Answer (score 18):

### He was not directing real armies until much later in the book

The point where Ender employes the leg freezing strategy is where he is still in Battle School, playing the zero-G laser tag "Battle Room" game that all kids their played.

He spends about 3 to 4 years there, before graduating, spending a few months earthside, and then traveling to Command School at Eros.

At Eros he interacts entirely with a simulator, and does not move around in zero-G and freeze his legs or direct others to. Instead he's directly controlling ships. (And even then, it's only after a few months of the using the simulator before they start giving him real battles instead of simulations.)

**So when Ender employed the leg freezing strategy, it did not translate to anything, because at the time he did this he was not directing human armies. It just translated to the forty kids he was commanding to freeze their own legs.**

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The freeze-the-leg trick was specific to the mechanics of the war games. It followed from the following observations:

1. Different parts of the body could be hit independently without taking you out of the game entirely.
2. Getting hit in the legs more than once was no worse, tactically speaking, then getting it once.
3. Holding your legs in front of your chest could protect your more "vital" areas from being hit.
4. It's really tiring having to hold your own legs in the position required by Observation #3.

The idea of *intentially* shooting yourself in the leg follows from the first three observations to a tactic that negates Observation #4. It's the thought process that lead to the discovery of this particular tactic, rather than the tactic itself, that marks Ender as a strong candidate for leading the actual war.

Comment: 5) Active battlesuits glow; freezing part of the battlesuit makes it stop glowing, so it reduces the visibility of the "soldier."

Comment: Never really thought about the lighting in Battle Room that much, and I haven't read the book in ages. Is that mentioned as a factor in devising the tactic?

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense. I kind of like the idea that some kid is playing age of empires or whatever, without realizing that he’s directing troops while at the same time the troops not realizing that their nonsensical orders are coming from some kid not realizing they are playing a games… but I guess that isn’t this story. 

Thanks for the thoughtful responses!

Comment: OP was asking what was happening "in the real world" everytime Ender did the freeze-the-leg trick (assuming that those games were also real life battles), not what Ender was able to apply the skill he learned from the trick to later on.

Answer (score -1):

I will contradict ibid said. It's not direct proof, but you can reasonably argue that he learns a couple of important tactical principles, that later translate to real battles, even when you realize freezing legs was in Battle School 0G training that had nothing to do with actual ship combat in Tactical/Command.

1. **Create your own environment**. Don't have a shield? Freeze your legs. Don't have a conglomeration of enemy ships to use M.D. device on? Blow it up on the planet.
2. **Sacrifice your own units when warranted**. Arguably, this was more of a lesson learned from the last battle ("*In that final battle in Battle School, he had won by ignoring the enemy, ignoring his own losses; he had moved against the enemy's gate*"). But the concept of using parts of yourself to sacrifice for tactical win also came from the freezing idea.

Comment: OP was asking what was happening "in the real world" everytime Ender did the freeze-the-leg trick (assuming that those games were also real life battles), not asking what Ender was able to apply the skill he learned from the trick to later on.

Comment: @ibid - yeah, I know that (now :). I was answering what he SHOULD have asked, which is whether that move had any impact on future actions in the book